# how to retrieve list of text from a view using robotium

Tags: java, android, robotium

I am doing a program for automation testing of android app using robotium.
I want to retrieve list of text from a view using robotium for the android device.

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = solo.getView(...);
if (view instanceof TextView) {
    String text = ((TextView)view).getText();
}
```